# Mean and variance of how much a random customer spends

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation, conditional-expectation

> Customers arrive at a store according to a Poisson process of rate $λ$ customers per hour. Each makes a purchase with probability $p$, independently. Given that a customer makes a purchase, the amount spent has mean $µ$ (in dollars) and variance $σ^2$.
>
> (a) Find the mean and variance of how much a random customer spends (note that the customer may spend nothing).

Let number of custumers be $N$~Pois(λt); $P(I_p=1)=p$; let $X_n$ be the amounth spent. Then, $E[X_1|I_p=1]=µ$; $Var(X_1|I_p=1)=σ^2$

$E(X_n|N=n)=E(X_n|I_p=1,N=n)p+E(X_n|I_p=0,N=n)q=Nµp$

$E[X_n]=E[E(X_n|N=n)]=E[Nµp]=µpE[N]=λtµp$

$Var(X_n)=E[Var(X_n|N=n)]+Var[E(X_n|N=n)]$, where

$Var(X_n|N=n)=E[Var(X_n|I_p=1,N=n)]+Var[E(X_n|I_p=1,N=n)]=E[Nσ^2]+Var[Nµ]=λtσ^2+λtµ^2=>Var(X_n)=E(λtσ^2+λtµ^2)+Var(Nµp)=λt(σ^2+µ^2+µ^2p^2)$

Is it right/wrong?

Comment: So mean and variance of the spending of a random customer depend on time $t$?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y$ denote the money spend by a random customer under condition that this customer makes a purchase. Then $\mathbb EY=\mu$ and $\mathsf{Var}Y=\sigma^2$.

Let $B\sim Bernoulli(p)$ and let $B$ and $Y$ be independent.

Then you are asked to find the expectation and variance of $BY$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then $E[BY]=E[B]E[Y]==pE[N]μ=λpμ$ and

Comment: No. $\mathbb EBY=\mathbb EB\mathbb EY=p\mu$. You are investigating the spendings of a randomly chosen customer. It is not relevant how busy it is in the store. So there is no part to play for $\lambda$.

Comment: but $Y_i$ is the amounth spent by $i$ customer, then total amounth is the sum $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}Y_i$. No? And as I got it there is given $E[Y_i]=μ$

Comment: " find mean and variance of how much **a** random customer spends.." You are looking at only **one** customer.

Comment: Ahhh... Thanks!